# How do I disable mouse acceleration AND adjust tracking speed in High Sierra?

Tags: mouse

The obvious answer you can find everywhere is:

`defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1`

which disables mouse acceleration, *but locks you at one sensitivity.*

**Old solutions:**

[SmoothMouse no longer works](http://dae.me/blog/2144/on-macos-sierra-support-and-the-future-of-smoothmouse/). [Mouse Acceleration Preferences Pane](http://triq.net/mac/mouse-acceleration) and [SteelSeries ExactMouse](https://downloads.steelseriescdn.com/drivers/tools/steelseries-exactmouse-tool.dmg) both behave the same as `com.apple.mouse.scaling -1` at all tracking speed settings (but without restart required).

Is it possible to disable mouse acceleration while still being able to adjust the sensitivity?

Comment: Maybe [Steermouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/)?

Comment: CursorSense from the same developer seems to still work, but I'm a little peeved I have to pay money to change my mouse sensitivity.

Comment: If you're in a trial period for CursorSense, you might be able to get an acceptable result from [Mouse Acceleration](http://triq.net/articles/mouse-acceleration-download).

Comment: Mouse Acceleration appears to offer an inverse setting scale which removes acceleration, but I can't tell that any of the values currently change anything related to speed when the displayed value is negative.

Comment: That's the Mouse Acceleration Preferences Pane I mentioned in my original post. It seems all the negative values are similar to what you get at -1. I imagine it's just setting `com.apple.mouse.scaling` without a need for restart.

Comment: I ended up ditching the Magic Mouse 2 and going with the Logitech MX Vertical. The MX Vertical has variable sensitivity built into the firmware, which with the `defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1` option, alleviates my problem.

Really disappointing that a basic feature like this was removed from macOS and the only solutions cost money.

Comment: the command doesn't work for me

Comment: The fact that this is a question is a HUGE FAIL on Apple's part. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Another update after moving to Catalina:
Mouse Acceleration Preferences Pane no longer works. I just have an alias in my `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`: `alias fix-mouse='defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1'`. I had to log out after running `fix-mouse` to make it stick. It seems to remember it even after subsequent OS updates, which is better than Mouse Acceleration Preferences Pane.

Comment: I use a Logitech Mouse too, and can disable acceleration (in terminal) and then adjust speed using the the Logitech Options software. This is on both Mojave and Monterey. 
@CharlieLaabs AFAIK this has NEVER been openly configurable in MacOS or OS X, at least since I've been using macs (2009). It's always the first thing I have to do when setting up a system, and it's utterly shameful that Apple has never allowed a checkbox in mouse settings for this. The Magic Mouse is an ergonomic disaster. Toss that thing in the trash.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nov 2021: [LinearMouse](https://github.com/lujjjh/LinearMouse) is actively developed & free.

A UI so no terminal messing. It can also help with the scroll wheel acceleration as well.

[image]

Comment: Incredible ! After so many years of hassle... I should definitely learn swift to help the project =)

Answer (score 18):

The built-in options are limited. To achieve your goal a combination of different software could be needed.

### Sensitivity and mouse acceleration

**Terminal**

Like you have already mentioned, the following setting needs to be applied to disable mouse acceleration.

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1
```

It can be a good idea to establish a script to automatically perform this action during login to ensure it is properly applied.

Alternatively, mouse acceleration can be configured using SteerMouse (presented below).

**SteerMouse**

SteerMouse can then be used to adjust your sensitivity. It does require a license, but it also resolves the issue.

Simply download and install the software, either from their [homepage](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/download.php) or by using e.g. Homebrew:

```
brew install --cask steermouse
```

The *Cursor* settings can then be adjusted to your liking. Acceleration should be left at 0, while sensitivity can be tuned to your preference.

> - Speed = ON

- Acceleration = 0
- Sensitivity = 0-2000

[image: SteerMouse cursor settings]

- If using e.g. BetterTouchTool, then remember to turn *Buttons*, *Wheel* and *Chords* off in SteerMouse. These are known to conflict and generate erratic mouse behavior, as they both utilize similar macOS API endpoints.

### Scrolling

Semi-related are also modifications to scrolling which can improve the Mac mouse usage experience.

**SmoothScroll**

Scrolling with a mouse on macOS can feel unnatural. To improve this one can utilize applications such as SmoothScroll for a better flowing scroll. Further adjustments can be made to customize the speed and related settings to ones need.

[image: SmoothScrool settings]

It can be downloaded and installed directly from the [homepage](https://www.smoothscroll.net/mac/), or by using e.g. Homebrew:

```
brew install --cask smoothscroll
```

**Scroll direction**

It can be preferential to have different scroll directions between the trackpad and mouse. This can be adjusted in *System Preferences* -> *Mouse*. Checking/unchecking *Scroll direction: Natural* modifies this behavior.

[image: Scroll direction - System Preferences]

### Notes

- The recommended options have been tested to work on macOS Ventura 13.2.1.
- Licenses might be required for the suggested software.
- I am in no way affiliated with the software developers, just a satisfied user. These are workarounds I have found when attempting to resolve the issue(s).

Comment: steermouse is a paid app

Comment: @MuhsinFatih Indeed. I have yet to find free solutions capable of achieving the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Under Big Sur, `defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1` still works but requires a restart. However once restarted and my MacBook Pro goes into sleep mode and comes out of it, the mouse acceleration is back again. It requires a full restart after each time it goes into sleep mode.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking for Big Sur:

[CursorSense](https://plentycom.jp/en/cursorsense/) is capable of this, however it is paid software.

Instead I found https://github.com/docwhat/killmouseaccel which is a free solution that will remove acceleration on a mouse or touchpad, *while maintaining the ability to adjust sensitivity*.

Launching it on startup is covered well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13372744

Answer (score 0):

Not a software solution (and I'm on Big Sur in 2021), so possibly not the answer you were looking for. But, I use a Logitech MX518 Hero which lets you store different DPI profiles physically on the mouse. I mainly use this mouse with Windows (which is where I set all the hardware profiles). But then when I swap over to MacOS machine with KVM, as long as I have the accel disabled via Terminal, then the mouse behaves exactly the same as it does on the Windows machine.

Comment: Unfortunately, this leads to pixel skips on Retina. I would need exactly 0.5x linear sensitivity to configure things the same as Windows.

Comment: Ah, when I use my MacBook with external keyboard and mouse, I'm also using an external (non-Retina) display.