# How to disable mouse acceleration in Catalina?

Tags: macos, mouse

The command I've seen from [How do I disable mouse acceleration AND adjust tracking speed in High Sierra?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/333989/150109)

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1
```

Doesn't change the mouse behaviour at all.

I don't know where to download SteelSeries exact mouse anymore (nor if it works). Ideally a solution should exist that doesn't use third party software.

I have a logitech G203, Macbook Pro 15", macOS Catalina 10.15.2.

Comment: Related answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/358540/90404

Comment: I used that SteerMouse app mentioned in the answer @TamásSengel linked to. It works, even though it seems to have reset all the configuration I had in the memory of my Logitech G502.